# Generate a unique hash/number for tracking on $wpdb insert

Tags: wpdb

I want to generate a unique hash/number that I can use for status tracking for an contest. I'm going to use this hash/number in a url created with [add_query_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/).

The url creation will look something like this:

```
$url = add_query_arg( array( 'id' => 'tracking_number_comes_here', 'email' => '$contest_object->email' ), $redirect_url );
```

That will output something like this:

```
www.example.dev/share/?id=tracking_number_comes_here&email=email@example.com
```

This is working fine, but I'm having a hard way to generate a unique hash/number to use as the tracking number.

A row is added to contest table when a participant submits his participation. I use wpdb to insert to my table:

```
    // Add user to db
    $addRow = $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->contest,
            array(
                'name' => $data['name'],    
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'shared_facebook' => 0,
                'shared_mail' => 0,
                'tracking' => $unique_hash_number
            )
    );
```

I think generating an 8 character hash from an integer with md5 were the integer is the participant ID will work.

```
$hash = substr(md5($id), 0, 8);
```

Is it possible to grab the participant id on insertion? or do I have to update the hash after the participant is added to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The userid will not exist until the user is inserted, you would need to do a second update for that. You may be better off using PHP's [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), perhaps with the user's email as a salt/prefix to avoid a race condition (however unlikely).